# Text changes when moving cursor over

Tags: terminal, cursor

I was modifying an email template and I noticed that when moving the cursor over a piece of code it changed.

Here is a screenshot from before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Vim version is 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04. Any idea what would make something like this happen?

Comment: This looks like a problem in your terminal emulator. Which terminal are you using? What's the TERM environment variable set to? You can also [try following these steps](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51), to make sure it's not a plugin or something in your vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal window isn't configured to display colors properly.

You can test whether this is the case by disabling color in vim and see if the problem goes away.

**Disables color features in vim:**

```
:syntax off
:set nohlsearch
:set t_Co=0
```

If this fixes it but you want color support, the next step I suggest is to check your terminal emulator and shell configuration for ANSI support.

Comment: it displays the colors properly, the photos are from when trying to replicate the behavior and ubuntu probably didn't recognized the code because i named the file test instead of test.php

Comment: but if i disable color features like you said it seems to work properly

Comment: try this before starting vim: `export TERM=xterm`